# Is centripetal acceleration independent of linear acceleration in accelerated circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, vectors, centripetal-force

Can we say that there is a relationship between them, or are they independent of each other? why?

Like does $a_c=v^2/r$ imply $a_c$ and $a_{tangential}$ are related?

I am very confused by this statement taken from a book.

[image]

Comment: it's better to say "tangential" and "centripetal" acceleration, I think, because when I hear "linear acceleration", I think of "the acceleration relative to the (x,y,z) coordinate system", which will be a mixture of the tangential and centripetal accelerations.

Answer (score 0):

They are somewhat related. Remember that $a_t=\frac{dv}{dt}$, so that $\frac{da_c}{dt}=\frac{2v}{r}\frac{dv}{dt}$, that is, the change in centripetal acceleration is proportional to the tangential acceleration. You can also get eliminating $v$:

$a_c=(\frac{\dot{a_c}}{2a_t})^2r$

Comment: Ok that's very helpful. I read in a book they were independent so I was very confused

Comment: Actually I'm going to add it to the question.

Comment: they are in the sense that they can take independent values, because you can set $\dot{a_c}$ to any value

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration vector is the vector sum of both components which are independent for sure, unless you impose a constraint (in this case the constraint is that the motion should happen in a circular trajectory with constant radius).

If you constraint motion to a circle of a fixed radius as the tangential velocity increases/decreases (due to a non-zero $a_{tangential}$) the value of $v$ will change in time, and that in turn will change the needed centripetal acceleration $a_c = v^2/r$ for mantaining the circular trajectory.

If, for example, we assume that $a_{tangential} = constant$ then you should expect a linear increase in tangential speed $v_{tangential} = \int a_{tangential} dt = a_{tangential}\cdot t$ as time, $t$, progresses. Since there is no radial speed ($v_{radial} = 0$) due to the fact that we want to mantain a circular trajectory with constant radius, $r = R = constant$ (or otherwise the object would radially get closer or farther from the center of the circunference), the total speed is

$v = \sqrt{v_{tangential}^2+v_{radial}^2} = |v_{tangential}| = |a_{tangential}\cdot t|$

Therefore we end up having

$a_{c} = a_{tangential}^2\cdot t^2 / R$

Which means that given a constant tangential acceleration the speed will increase linearly and the centripetal acceleration needed to mantain the circular trajectory will increase geometrically.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is a vector so we can resolve them into linear and circular acceleration. For example, think of swirling a bob on a thread whilst accelerating in a car or train, or plane for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

They are two (orthogonal) components of the (one) acceleration vector. What they have in common is whatever forces generate the acceleration.

If you consider an object moving along a path, at some instant the velocity vector is decomposed into a magnitude $v$ and a direction $\hat{t}$ which is *always* tangent to the path by definition

$$ \vec{v} = v \; \hat{t} \tag{1} $$

How the velocity vector changes with time is described by the acceleration vector that is decomposed along *two* perpendicular directions

$$ \vec{a} = \dot{v} \; \hat{t} + \tfrac{v^2}{r} \; \hat{n} \tag{2} $$

where $\hat{n}$ is the vector perpendicular to the path and pointing towards the center of orbit (rotation center), $r$ is the radius of turn, and $\dot{v}$ is the tangential acceleration component, or the rate of change of speed $v$.

You are asking if the two component magnitudes $\dot{v}$ and $\tfrac{v^2}{r}$ are related to each other. The answer is that they represent values with a physical meaning, as in a change in speed, and radius of rotation, and thus just a convenient way of decomposing an acceleration vector.